# "Illegal schematic variable(s)" in code generated by proof (cases rule: ...)`

Tags: isabelle, isar

I defined a cases rule for `case_option` in the hope of making some proofs more readable.
However, when applying it with `proof (cases rule: ...)` and using the code snippet suggested by the `proof` statement,
the Isar `case` syntax tells me `Illegal schematic variable(s) in case ...`, even though the rule works in other cases.

```
lemma case_option_cases[case_names None Some]: (* removing the "case_names" tag does not solve the issue *)
  assumes "x = None ==> P a"
    and "!!y. x = Some y ==> P (b y)"
  shows "P (case x of None => a | Some y => b y)"
  using assms unfolding option.split_sel by blast

notepad
begin

  fix P :: "'y => bool" and x :: "'x option" and a :: "'y" and b :: "'x => 'y"

  (* sanity check *)
  assume "x = None ==> P a" and "!!y. x = Some y ==> P (b y)"
  then have "P (case x of None => a | Some y => b y)"
    by (cases rule: case_option_cases) (* also works just "by (rule ...)" *)

  have "P (case x of None => a | Some y => b y)"
  proof (cases rule: case_option_cases) (* this line generates and suggests the following structure *)
    case None (* Illegal schematic variable(s) in case "None" *)
    then show ?thesis sorry
  next
    case (Some y) (* same here *)
    then show ?thesis sorry
  qed

end
```

Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: A quick fix is to explicitly instantiate the required schematic variables of `case_option_cases`, i.e., use `proof (cases rule: case_option_cases[of x P a b])`.

Comment: I'd like to make an additional remark: I think the fundamental cause of the issues you face with your custom case analysis rule is that the `cases` method works smoothly with elimination rules (such as the built-in `option.exhaust` rule, which is the default rule for `cases` with `option`) since these do not change the goal. I think your `case_option_cases` lemma is closely related to `option.split`, which works well with the Simplifier (in fact, you proved `case_option_cases` by resorting to `option.split_sel`, although `using assms by (simp split: option.split)` works too and is simpler).

Comment: `option.exhaust` (and similarly, `.induct`) work well, but fail to eliminate the lengthy `case` expression, only half of which is relevant for each case.  
`option.split` is indeed very closely related to what I am trying to achieve. Is there any built-in way to apply the split as a proof starter?

Comment: Please could you elaborate on the issue regarding the lengthy `case` expression?

Comment: Regarding the automatic application of split rules, you can add rules to the Splitter by using the attribute `split` when stating your lemma, i.e., `lemma "..." [split] ...`.

Comment: Regarding the lengthy `case` expressions: often I find ones of the form `complicated_predicate (case x of None => long_expr | Some y => longer_expr y)`. It quickly becomes tedious to work with these long expressions and proofs become hard to read, therefore I wanted a single-step tactic that gets rid of the `case` and instead exposes the simplified cases directly. Both methods in the answer achieve that.

Comment: There is a built-in way to apply split rules: `split <rule>` which is equivalent to `subst <rule>`, however. `proof (split option.split, safe)` generates the same subgoals as the methods in my answer, but does not generate cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Javier points out, the solution is to **instantiate the variables** (only `x` seems to be required).
However, `cases` has this already built in:

```
proof (cases x rule: case_option_cases)
(* generates the following template *)
  case None
  then show ?thesis (* replace by "P a" *) sorry
next
  case (Some y)
  then show ?thesis (* replace by "P (b y)" *) sorry
qed
```

Note that the generated code still fails as `?thesis` does not match the new goals after applying `cases`. Instead, the goals have to be stated explicitly.

---

Even better (although less intuitive), **using `induction` in place of `cases`** automatically instantiates the relevant variables, with the added bonus of providing the correct goals as `?case`:

```
proof (induction rule: case_option_cases)
(* generates the following template *)
  case None
  then show ?case sorry
next
  case (Some y)
  then show ?case sorry
qed
```

Comment: `proof (cases x rule: case_option_cases)` doesn't seem to work for me.

Comment: For me `cases x ...` solves the `Illegal schematic variable(s) ...` error, which is the issue in question. I am aware that the generated code still fails because `?thesis` no longer matches the goal (has to be stated explicitly: `then show "P a" ...`). I believe this is a limitation of `cases`, however. Could you describe what happens when you use `cases x ...`?

Comment: Precisely, what happens is that `?thesis` no longer matches the goal and has to be stated explicitly. I think that should be part of the answer to the original question.

Comment: Thanks for editing your answer to include my suggestion.

Comment: I think it's worth pointing out that when explicitly instantiating *all* the schematic variables, as I mentioned in my very first comment, the correct goals are generated as `?case`'s.

Comment: This is some seriously non-intuitive behavior (although it would make sense that this is what `induction` does internally). Even weirder, `cases x P a ...` generates `?case` for `case None` and suggests it in the template, but not for `case (Some y)`. And `cases x P a b ...` fails with `Rule has fewer variables than instantiations given`.